# Adding sum of terms with alternating signs

Tags: recursion, numbers

Probably a noob question but I can't think of an elegant way to solve the following in a general way. I think I saw it on Euler a while back and it's been bugging me for a while.

Say you have a complex number z, I want a function that can do the following.

```
s = +/-z^0
s = +/-z^0 + +/-z^1
s = +/-z^0 + +/-z^1 + +/-z^2
...
```

Does anyone know a good way to solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution. zExp is an array of precomputed exponentiated terms.

```
void sumSeries(zSum, zExp, count) {
    if (count == 0) {
        zSum += zExp[0];
        doSomethingWith(zSum);
        zSum -= 2*zExp[0];
        doSomethingWith(zSum);
    } else {
        zSum += zExp[0];
        sumSeries(zSum + zExp[count], zExp, count);
        zSum -= 2*zExp[0];
        sumSeries(zSum - zExp[count], zExp, count);
    }
}
```